# Can't download jquery to learn query

Tags: jquery

I am currently doing a course through Udemy on coding and I keep getting a new page filled with code instead of downloading the file to my computer in order to include it in my own page creations.

I go to the download tab and when clicking on any of the links it just opens a page full of code instead like the following:

```
/*! jQuery v3.5.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */
!function(e,t){"use strict";"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=e.document?t(e,!0):function(e){if(!e.document)throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");return t(e)}:t(e)}("undefined"!=typeof window?window:this,function(C,e){"use strict";var t=[],r=Object.getPrototypeOf,s=t.slice,g=t.flat?function(e){return t.flat.call(e)}:function(e){return t.concat.apply([],e)},u=t.push,i=t.indexOf,n={},o=n.toString,v=n.hasOwnProperty,a=v.toString,l=a.call(Object),y={},m=function(e){return"function"==typeof e&&"number"!=typeof e.nodeType},x=function(e){return null!=e&&e===e.window},E=C.document,c={type:!0,src:!0,nonce:!0,noModule:!0};function b(e,t,n){var r,i,o=(n=n||E).createElement("script");if(o.text=e,t)for(r in c)(i=t[r]||t.getAttribute&&t.getAttribute(r))&&o.setAttribute(r,i);n.head.appendChild(o).parentNode.removeChild(o)}function w(e){return null==e?e+"":"object"==typeof e||"function"==typeof e?n[o.call(e)]||"object":typeof e}var f="3.5.1",S=function(e,t){return new S.fn.init(e,t)};function p(e){var t=!!e&&"length"in e&&e.length,n=w(e);return!m(e)&&!x(e)&&("array"===n||0===t||"number"==typeof t&&0<t&&t-1 in e)}S.fn=S.prototype={jquery:f,constructor:S,length:0,toArray:function(){return s.call(this)},get:function(e){return null==e?s.call(this):e<0?this[e+this.length]:this[e]},pushStack:function(e){var t=S.merge(this.constructor(),e);return t.prevObject=this,t},each:function(e){return S.each(this,e)},map:function(n){return this.pushStack(S.map(this,function(e,t){return n.call(e,t,e)}))},slice:function(){return this.pushStack(s.apply(this,arguments))},first:function(){return this.eq(0)},last:function(){return this.eq(-1)},even:function(){return this.pushStack(S.grep(this,function(e,t){return(t+1)%2}))},odd:function(){return this.pushStack(S.grep(this,function(e,t){return t%2}))},eq:function(e){var t=this.length,n=+e+(e<0?t:0);return this.pushStack(0<=n&&n<t?[this[n]]:[])},end:function(){return this.prevObject||this.constructor()},push:u,sort:t.sort,splice:t.splice},S.extend=S.fn.extend=function(){var e,t,n,r,i,o,a=arguments[0]||{},s=1,u=arguments.length,l=!1;for("boolean"==typeof a&&(l=a,a=arguments[s]||{},s++),"object"==typeof a||m(a)||(a={}),s===u&&(a=this,s--);s<u;s++)if(null!=(e=arguments[s]))for(t in e)r=e[t],"__proto__"!==t&&a!==r&&(l&&r&&(S.isPlainObject(r)||(i=Array.isArray(r)))?(n=a[t],o=i&&!Array.isArray(n)?[]:i||S.isPlainObject(n)?n:{},i=!1,a[t]=S.extend(l,o,r)):void 0!==r&&(a[t]=r));return a},S.extend({expando:"jQuery"+(f+Math.random()).replace(/\D/g,""),isReady:!0,error:function(e){throw new Error(e)},noop:function(){},isPlainObject:function(e){var t,n;return!(!e||"[object Object]"!==o.call(e))&&(!(t=r(e))||"function"==typeof(n=v.call(t,"constructor")&&t.constructor)&&a.call(n)===l)},isEmptyObject:function(e){var t;for(t in e)return!1;return!0},globalEval:function(e,t,n){b(e,{nonce:t&&t.nonce},n)},each:function(e,t){var n,r=0;if(p(e)){for(n=e.length;r<n;r++)if(!1===t.call(e[r],r,e[r]))break}else for(r in e)if(!1===t.call(e[r],r,e[r]))break;return e},makeArray:function(e,t){var n=t||[];return null!=e&&(p(Object(e))?S.merge(n,"string"==typeof e?[e]:e):u.call(n,e)),n},inArray:function(e,t,n){return null==t?-1:i.call(t,e,n)},merge:function(e,t){for(var n=+t.length,r=0,i=e.length;r<n;r++)e[i++]=t[r];return e.length=i,e},grep:function(e,t,n){for(var r=[],i=0,o=e.length,a=!n;i<o;i++)!t(e[i],i)!==a&&r.push(e[i]);return r},map:function(e,t,n){var r,i,o=0,a=[];if(p(e))for(r=e.length;o<r;o++)null!=(i=t(e[o],o,n))&&a.push(i);else for(o in e)null!=(i=t(e[o],o,n))&&a.push(i);return g(a)},guid:1,support:y}),"function"==typeof Symbol&&(S.fn[Symbol.iterator]=t[Symbol.iterator]),S.each("Boolean Number String Function Array Dat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather thank clicking on the link, instead right click and select save link as, save file as or similar and that will save the file to your computer.

Alternativaly, select all on that page it takes you to and copy the contents, then paste it into a new file which you'll save as jquery.js.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference it to the page with script tag.

Some quick examples:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can add JQuery to your html project by adding this tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```